# I have a mess with environment variables in react

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, development-environment, package.json

I'm starting a project in React and I need to configure different environments.
In the `package.json` I have this scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "sh -ac '.env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts start'",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "dev": "Set REACT_APP_ENV=dev && npm run start",
    "pre": "Set REACT_APP_ENV=pre && npm run start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject" }
```

In the same route as the package.json (the root of the project) I have two files, .env.dev and .env.pre and inside this files I only have two variables:

`REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=pre`

`REACT_APP_TITLE= NEW TITLE`

**When I run `npm run dev` I get this error:**

```
sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts start'
sh: line 0: .: .env.dev: file not found
```

I thougt that the `.env` files have to be at the root of the project but now I'm doubting

Comment: Are you missing a dot? `"start": "sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts start'"`